# JQuery show DIV on another DIV on mouseover

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I know this may have a simple solution but I'm a Jquery noob. Please, help.
How can I show a DIV on another DIV on mouseover?

Example, I have this:

```
<div class="box"> Info about a game </div>
```

I want to "overlay" another div on the div "box"

```
<div class="overlay"> Play </div>
```

How can I do that with JQuery?

Sorry and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to only display `overlay` when hovering over `box`.

You could use CSS psuedo [`:hover`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp):

```
<div class="box">
    Info about a game
    <div class="overlay"> Play </div>
</div>​

div.box div.overlay
{
    display:none;
}

​div.box:hover div.overlay
{
 display:block;   
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/BC4eY/

---

If you would prefer to use animation/jquery to show/hide the `overlay` you can use the following:

```
$(function(){
    $(".box").hover(function(){
      $(this).find(".overlay").fadeIn();
    }
                    ,function(){
                        $(this).find(".overlay").fadeOut();
                    }
                   );        
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/BC4eY/2/

Comment: Yes, you're correct. But is that compatible with all browsers?

Comment: @Splugged It's compatible with a large majority of browsers http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: @Splugged See my edit. I've provided an animated jquery version too.

Comment: Great! That's what I was searching for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can have another DIV element with class 'about' that will be located where you want.
And will have CSS style:
opacity:0;

Then in JS you have to write little script, that will be located in onload / ready function, something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.box').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.overlay').fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    $(this).children('.overlay').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

If this element will be overlaying something on top, then it is better to use CSS attribute 'display:none' to prevent this transparent element taking over mouse events.

Comment: This won't work if there are multiple `box` on the page. Use `$(this)` instead. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10087695/370103

Comment: This is not exact code, and is just for example how to make it. If user need multiple DIV elements to be shown / hidden, then he keeps it that way, if he needs more specific, he can go your way or be more specific in selecting objects using jquery selector, for example using ID instead of CLASS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with native JavaScript (no jQuery library needed). If you're not using [ES6](http://es6-features.org/#Constants) you can replace the [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with regular old [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function):

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

var init = () => {
  overlay.style.display = 'none'; //hide by default when page is shown

  box.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    overlay.style.display = 'inline';
  });

  box.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    overlay.style.display = 'none';
  });
};

init();
```

```html
<div id="box"> Info about a game<br />
  <div id="overlay">Play</div>
</div>
```